# Escaping Quotes in Rails Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have Merchant Table which has the following fields

```
Merchant(id: integer, name: string, logo: string, description: text, categories: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

I want to run first_or_create query with name attribute. The problem is the name column contains single quotes, for example Brandy's Boy.

```
mname = "brandy's boy"
conds = "lower(name) = #{mname}"

Merchant.where(conds)

Merchant Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE "merchants"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND (lower(name) = 'brandy's boy ') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

OutPut:

```
#<Merchant::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000055d0f72a2ce0>
```

But this gives me the output when I run static query.

```
Merchant.where("lower(name) = ?", 'Brandy\'s Boy'.downcase)

Merchant Load (3.7ms)  SELECT  "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE "merchants"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND (lower(name) = 'brandy''s boy') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]

#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Merchant id: 1413, name: "Brandy's Boy", logo: nil, description: "ABC", categories: [], created_at: "2020-07-17 07:32:29", updated_at: "2020-07-17 07:32:29">]>
```

But the variable mname is populated in a loop and it is dynamic. So in that case I need to escape the single quotes and get the desired result (existing Brandy's Boy Merchant Object)

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to interpolate to create the arguments for `where`, just bind it/them:

```
Merchant.where("lower(name) = ?", mname)
```

Active Record will take care of that and your query will most likely look like this:

```
SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" WHERE (lower(name) = 'brandy''s boy')
```

Escaping is doing in the internals of the framework, from the docs:

> If an array is passed, then the first element of the array is treated
> as a template, and the remaining elements are inserted into the
> template to generate the condition. Active Record takes care of
> building the query to avoid injection attacks, and will convert from
> the ruby type to the database type where needed. Elements are inserted
> into the string in the order in which they appear.

```
User.where(["name = ? and email = ?", "Joe", "joe@example.com"])
# SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'Joe' AND email = 'joe@example.com';
```

Doing:

```
Merchant.where(["lower(name) = ?", mname])
```

Is pretty much the *same* as doing:

```
Merchant.where("lower(name) = ?", mname)
```

So your query is handled as stated above.